# How to skip webflow definition(flow.xml) scan for third party jars

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

Is there away we can restrict spring webflow definition (flow.xml) scan to look only for specific jar pattern from my WEB-INF/LIB folder? 
My web application having nearly 700 jars in WEB-INF/lib folder in which i want the scan to be done only for specified jar name pattern (eg: jar name starts with "com.xxx").
I have already done location pattern scan, but I do want to restrict number of jars scan, so that it would be faster.

Thanks,
Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm understanding your question correctly. How is your "flowRegistry" bean configured? Or better yet your entire spring webflow config?

**Possible solutions:**

**1.**   You can pass in wild cards in the "**flow-location-pattern**" (e.g value="/**/*-flow.xml") to provide a search pattern.

**2.** You can also set the **base-path** attribute on the flow-registry to indicate where the root directory of the flow (scanning) will start.

**3.** finally you can also explicitly declare your flow using the **flow-location path="..."**

The sample config below demonstrates how to use all 3 possible configs stated above.

**Sample config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config.xsd">
```

```
<!-- The registry of executable flow definitions --> 
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows/s" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="/**/*-flow.xml" />
        <!--  <webflow:flow-location path="/flows/main-flow.xml" />-->
    </webflow:flow-registry>
```

Comment: I am already using the location pattern like <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="classpath*:/META-INF/resources/xyzweb/**/*-flow.xml" />.  Whatever the location pattern we give, spring does scan for all the jars under WEB-INF/lib directory. I want to know how could we filter those jar scans so that spring does scan only  in the given jar name matching the filter criteria. Eg: In my WEB-INF/lib directory, if I have 700 jars and I knew there are only 10 jars which should be scanned to look for flow.xml files (rest all are other dependency jars like logging, spring core jars).

Comment: I don't think think you should be scanning your lib directory. I suspect your project structure does NOT use standard convention. The resource loader web-flow uses is just the standard resource loader used by all spring projects (spring-core.jar). I recommend placing a break points at the following locations: 1) org.springframework.webflow.config.FlowRegistryFactoryBean registerFlowLocationPatterns()   2)   org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver getResources(String locationPattern).    Try to see why the lib directory is being scanned.

Comment: Why are your flow.xml files embedded in jars?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We have module based apps. Every module will have its own jar and its own resource flow xmls). When we use classpath*: in the location pattern, spring resource loader does scan all files in the classpath(includes lib folder as well). Let me check if there is a way i can restrict that list of jars

Comment: You might need to implement your own custom ResourceLoader http://stackoverflow.com/a/19547459/1041083 to filter on those specific jars only. Another possibility which might be less intrusive is to extend  FlowDefinitionResourceFactory and inject it into FlowRegistryFactoryBean.flowResourceFactory

Comment: Unfortunately since you have a non standard configuration only 'hacky' solutions will make it work. Because you want to use the lib directory for (2) separate functions. 1. for class loading and 2. for reading flow files.